# whenever I enter -1, nothing happens

Tags: c

Question: Ask the user to enter unlimited amount of numbers but will terminate when the sentinel (flag) value -1 is entered (use WHILE statement).
Your program will print one outputs: maximum number

Whenever I enter -1, nothing happens.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
    int number=0;
    int max;
    printf("Enter numbers: ");
    while(scanf("%d",&number)!=-1) {
        if(number>max) {
            max=number;
        }
    }
    printf("The max value is %d \n",max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're comparing the *return value* of scanf to -1, not `&number`.

Comment: Your post has some problems.  Avoid pleas for help; they will have the opposite effect of what you intended.  Especially avoid pleas for help in the titles of your questions.  Very rarely are you going to need both the `c` and `c++` tags at the same time; pick one.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing the return value of `scanf` to -1. You should be comparing `number` to -1.

Answer (score 1):

You checked the return value of `scanf()`, but you didn't check the value of `number`. Check it.

Also Using the value of `max` without initializing invokes *undefined behavior*, so you have to initialize that first.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h> /* for using INT_MIN */

int main(void) {
    int number=0;
    int max=INT_MIN; /* initialize max */
    printf("Enter numbers: ");
    while(scanf("%d",&number)==1 && number!=-1) { /* check value of number */
        if(number>max) {
            max=number;
        }
    }
    printf("The max value is %d \n",max);
    return 0;
}
```

Also I changed the `scanf()` check from `!=-1` to `==1` so that it won't fall into an infinite loop when non-numeric strings like `hoge` are entered.

Comment: The line "int max=INT_MIN;" is giving me error when I compile and run it

Comment: @oluidowu3 [This code should work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/o2eCFWeVIiWRGC6G). What error do you get?

Comment: I don't what kind of error but it's highlight this line "int max=INT_MIN;"  with red